# How to make text visible over svg image in tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

How to make my text visible over svg image using tailwind css ? I tried using z-index but it didn't worked out ! What should i do ?

my code is as :

```
 <body class="relative">
 <svg class="absolute z-10"> some path </svg>

<div class="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 z-20">

 some code here 
</div>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: provide necessary code, so someone can try.

Answer (score 1):

More code can be helpful in order to give you a more precise solution for your case, but I'll suggest this solution:

Remove the `absolute` positioning from your `<svg>`, and remove the z-index utilities from all classes. apply `absolute` to your text and define the position with `absolute` utilities such as `top-24`. Lastly, apply `w-full` to your text to maintain it at the center of the screen.

Because your text is `absolute` and your `svg` is a `block`, the text will be displayed on top of the `svg`.

```html
<body class="relative">
  <svg width="1100" height="500">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="400" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </svg>
  <div class="flex w-full items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 absolute top-24">some code here</div>
</body>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WpqTvGarxw)

Comment: Yes I got answer ! Z index only works with absolute, relative or positioning elements only. That's why that z index was worthless even if I value it more.